# SPARKLINE error when data-pull cell contains formula. Is there a workaround for this?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to have the data cell for a `=SPARKLINE` bar graph pull data from another sheet. For some reason, `=SPARKLINE` doesn't recognise the cell's data if it's pulled using a formula. Is there any workaround for this, please?

I've tried pulling the data in multiple ways, pulling into different cells first from the same sheet. I've also tried pulling the data using `=TEXT`, but doesn't seem to recognize it.

Example:

In Cell A1 of Sheet2, I have the formula `='Sheet1'!I21`, so Cell A1 on Sheet2 will display the same content as what is in Cell I21 on Sheet1.

On Sheet2, I have a SPARKLINE graph in Cell A2, with the code of

```
=sparkline(A1,{"charttype","bar";"max",100;"color1","#1A73E8"})
```

in an attempt to pull the data from Cell A1.

I have alternatively tried

```
=sparkline((text(A1,"#")),{"charttype","bar";"max",100;"color1","#1A73E8"})
```

The `=SPARKLINE` command doesn't appear to recognize the data in cell A1 on Sheet2, providing the error of

> SPARKLINE requires more data points. Expected: 1, found: 0.

Say Cell I21 on Sheet1 has a value of "20". If I replace the formula on cell A1 of Sheet2, the `=SPARKLINE` chart will work fine. If I use the formula to pull the data, I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around a little more, I was able to find a solution. Using the =VALUE formula seemed to fix this. So, instead of ='Sheet1'!I21, =value('Sheet1'!I21) worked just fine. Just in case anyone finds the same issue, I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
=sparkline(A1,{"charttype","bar";"max",100;"color1","#1A73E8"})
```

works, so you have some issue other than syntax. Maybe locale?

[image: SO54291840 example]

IMPORTRANGE won't necessarily break the above - Text format would however.

Comment: It's strange, because that works for me, *unless* there's a formula in cell A1 where the data is being pulled from another sheet. If A1 contains a raw number value, it's fine. I can't see the locale being an issue here. It just appears to be an issue with the way =SPARKLINE handles formulas from where it's trying to pull the number value.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've checked it further, and it would appear that the source of the issue is that Sheet1!I21 pulls the data from an =IMPORTRANGE function. Manually typing the value into Sheet1!I21 resolves the issue. I'm not sure why this would cause an issue, but apparently it does. Are you able to re-create this, at all? I wonder if it's just the sheet I'm using, or an issue with it being =IMPORTRANGEd. 

Thanks again.